# "nohup ./filename.sh" not working in tSSH talend component

Tags: talend

I'm using the tssh component to unzip a file, then delete the zip folder on a host which works fine.

The problem is when I try to run a .sh file in the same directory. In the commands for the tSSh component I have added the command

```
nohup filename.sh > outfile.out
```

in which case I get the error

> no such file or directory

I have also tried

```
nohup ./filename.sh > outfile.out
```

but now the error is

> ./filename.sh command not found

All I need to do is execute the sh file.

Comment: check if you are in the same directory where filename.sh is there.

Comment: Hey, yeah i'm in the same directory

Comment: is the file executable, otherwise use "chmod 777 filename.sh"

Comment: the file is executable, and i can execute the file from putty.

Comment: It may have been that i wasn't using pseudo terminal option, trying that now

Comment: Pseudo Terminal works for me now

Answer (score 0):

Is your home directory the place where you expect to find the script filename.sh?
If yes, maybe you have a "cd" in your startup file.
If not, try to give 2 commands for nohup:
`` nohup `$(cd yourDirectoryPath ; ./filename.sh > outfile.out) ``
If you can't retrieve the result in outfile.out, check for nohup.out (and remove the redirection from the command line).
Hope this helps.
TRF